# How can I avoid loop function in R?

Tags: r

I ran into a R problem. I tried to use mutate, lapply ect., while avoiding using loops (for, while...), but I cannot figure out how to do it.

The work is like this. My data frame df has three variables x1, x2 and x3. I hope to generate three new variables x1_ordered, x2_ordered, x3_ordered based on x1, x2 and x3:

```
x1_ordered = 11 if x1 == 2
x1_ordered = 12 if x1 == 1
x1_ordered = 13 if x1 == 3
x1_ordered = 14 if x1 == 4
....
```

The same is true for x2 and x3.

I know using `for` loop can achieve this by 3 iterations, but my question is how to do it by using built-in or my own made-up function?

Comment: You should be able to use `mutate` and `across` with `case_when` to do this if the map from the original values to the new values is the same for `x1` `x2` and `x3`.  If you post some data, we could probably help more.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one such way using some sample data

```
    df=data.frame(
      "x1"=1:5,
      "x2"=6:10
    )
    
    map=list(
      df,
      data.frame("x1"=1:5,"x1_ordered"=5:1),
      data.frame("x2"=6:10,"x2_ordered"=10:6)
    )
    
    Reduce(merge,map)

  x2 x1 x1_ordered x2_ordered
1  6  1          5         10
2  7  2          4          9
3  8  3          3          8
4  9  4          2          7
5 10  5          1          6
```

**Note**: this will iteratively merge by each element of the list by all the common columns.

Answer (score 0):

Without access to your data, I might be off mark here, but you can adjust the following to your data :

```
# fake data
df <- data.frame(x1 = sample(1:4, size = 50, replace = TRUE),
                 x2 = sample(1:4, size = 50, replace = TRUE),
                 x3 = sample(1:4, size = 50, replace = TRUE)
)

library(tidyverse)

newdf <-
df  %>%
  mutate(across(everything(),
                ~case_when(.x == 2 ~ 11,
                           .x == 1 ~ 12,
                           .x == 3 ~ 13,
                           .x == 4 ~ 14),
                .names = "{.col}_ordered"
                )
         )
```